# Kubelet - failed to "CreatePodSandbox" for coredns; failed to set bridge addr: could not add ip addr to "cni0": permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, podman, cni, cri-o

## EDIT 1

In response to the comments I have included additional information.

```
$ kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system
NAME                                                  READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-66bff467f8-lkwfn                              0/1     ContainerCreating   0          7m8s
coredns-66bff467f8-pcn6b                              0/1     ContainerCreating   0          7m8s
etcd-masternode                                       1/1     Running             0          7m16s
kube-apiserver-masternode                             1/1     Running             0          7m16s
kube-controller-manager-masternode                    1/1     Running             0          7m16s
kube-proxy-7zrjn                                      1/1     Running             0          7m8s
kube-scheduler-masternode                             1/1     Running             0          7m16s
```

### More systemd logs

```
...
Jun 16 16:18:59 masternode kubelet[6842]: E0616 16:18:59.313433    6842 remote_runtime.go:105] RunPodSandbox from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create pod network sandbox k8s_coredns-66bff467f8-pcn6b_kube-system_d5fe7a46-c32d-4fa3-b1b3-fe5a28983e08_0(cc72c59e22145274e47ca417c274af99591d0008baf2bf13364538b7debb57d3): failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
Jun 16 16:18:59 masternode kubelet[6842]: E0616 16:18:59.313512    6842 kuberuntime_sandbox.go:68] CreatePodSandbox for pod "coredns-66bff467f8-pcn6b_kube-system(d5fe7a46-c32d-4fa3-b1b3-fe5a28983e08)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create pod network sandbox k8s_coredns-66bff467f8-pcn6b_kube-system_d5fe7a46-c32d-4fa3-b1b3-fe5a28983e08_0(cc72c59e22145274e47ca417c274af99591d0008baf2bf13364538b7debb57d3): failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
Jun 16 16:18:59 masternode kubelet[6842]: E0616 16:18:59.313532    6842 kuberuntime_manager.go:727] createPodSandbox for pod "coredns-66bff467f8-pcn6b_kube-system(d5fe7a46-c32d-4fa3-b1b3-fe5a28983e08)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create pod network sandbox k8s_coredns-66bff467f8-pcn6b_kube-system_d5fe7a46-c32d-4fa3-b1b3-fe5a28983e08_0(cc72c59e22145274e47ca417c274af99591d0008baf2bf13364538b7debb57d3): failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
Jun 16 16:18:59 masternode kubelet[6842]: E0616 16:18:59.313603    6842 pod_workers.go:191] Error syncing pod d5fe7a46-c32d-4fa3-b1b3-fe5a28983e08 ("coredns-66bff467f8-pcn6b_kube-system(d5fe7a46-c32d-4fa3-b1b3-fe5a28983e08)"), skipping: failed to "CreatePodSandbox" for "coredns-66bff467f8-pcn6b_kube-system(d5fe7a46-c32d-4fa3-b1b3-fe5a28983e08)" with CreatePodSandboxError: "CreatePodSandbox for pod \"coredns-66bff467f8-pcn6b_kube-system(d5fe7a46-c32d-4fa3-b1b3-fe5a28983e08)\" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create pod network sandbox k8s_coredns-66bff467f8-pcn6b_kube-system_d5fe7a46-c32d-4fa3-b1b3-fe5a28983e08_0(cc72c59e22145274e47ca417c274af99591d0008baf2bf13364538b7debb57d3): failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to \"cni0\": permission denied"
Jun 16 16:19:09 masternode kubelet[6842]: E0616 16:19:09.256408    6842 remote_runtime.go:105] RunPodSandbox from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create pod network sandbox k8s_coredns-66bff467f8-lkwfn_kube-system_f0187bfd-89a2-474c-b843-b00875183c77_0(1aba005509e85f3ea7da3fc48ab789ae3a10ba0ffefc152d1c4edf65693befe2): failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
Jun 16 16:19:09 masternode kubelet[6842]: E0616 16:19:09.256498    6842 kuberuntime_sandbox.go:68] CreatePodSandbox for pod "coredns-66bff467f8-lkwfn_kube-system(f0187bfd-89a2-474c-b843-b00875183c77)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create pod network sandbox k8s_coredns-66bff467f8-lkwfn_kube-system_f0187bfd-89a2-474c-b843-b00875183c77_0(1aba005509e85f3ea7da3fc48ab789ae3a10ba0ffefc152d1c4edf65693befe2): failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
Jun 16 16:19:09 masternode kubelet[6842]: E0616 16:19:09.256525    6842 kuberuntime_manager.go:727] createPodSandbox for pod "coredns-66bff467f8-lkwfn_kube-system(f0187bfd-89a2-474c-b843-b00875183c77)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create pod network sandbox k8s_coredns-66bff467f8-lkwfn_kube-system_f0187bfd-89a2-474c-b843-b00875183c77_0(1aba005509e85f3ea7da3fc48ab789ae3a10ba0ffefc152d1c4edf65693befe2): failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
Jun 16 16:19:09 masternode kubelet[6842]: E0616 16:19:09.256634    6842 pod_workers.go:191] Error syncing pod f0187bfd-89a2-474c-b843-b00875183c77 ("coredns-66bff467f8-lkwfn_kube-system(f0187bfd-89a2-474c-b843-b00875183c77)"), skipping: failed to "CreatePodSandbox" for "coredns-66bff467f8-lkwfn_kube-system(f0187bfd-89a2-474c-b843-b00875183c77)" with CreatePodSandboxError: "CreatePodSandbox for pod \"coredns-66bff467f8-lkwfn_kube-system(f0187bfd-89a2-474c-b843-b00875183c77)\" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create pod network sandbox k8s_coredns-66bff467f8-lkwfn_kube-system_f0187bfd-89a2-474c-b843-b00875183c77_0(1aba005509e85f3ea7da3fc48ab789ae3a10ba0ffefc152d1c4edf65693befe2): failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to \"cni0\": permission denied"
... (repeats over and over again)
```

I have sucessfully installed Kubernetes 1.18 with CRI-0 1.18 and set up a cluster using kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16. However, the "coredns"-nodes are stuck at "ContainerCreating". I followed the official Kubernetes install instructions.

### What I have tried

I tried installing Calico but that didn't fix it. I also tried manually changing the cni0 interface to UP but that also didn't work. The problem apparently lies somewhere with the bridged traffic but I followed the Kubernetes tutorial and enabled it.

In my research of the problem I stumbled upon promising solutions and tutorials but none of them solved the problem. ([Rancher GitHub Issue](https://github.com/rancher/rke/issues/1788), [CRI-O GitHub Page](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/blob/master/tutorials/kubeadm.md), [Projectcalico](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/2322), [Kubernetes tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/))

### Firewall-cmd

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --state
running
$ sudo firewall-cmd --version
0.7.0
```

### Systemd logs

[Image of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2KSe.png)
because pasting the entire log would be ugly.

### uname -r

```
4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1.x86_64 (Centos 8)
```

### CRI-O

```
crio --version
crio version
Version:       1.18.1
GitCommit:     5cbf694c34f8d1af19eb873e39057663a4830635
GitTreeState:  clean
BuildDate:     2020-05-25T19:01:44Z
GoVersion:     go1.13.4
Compiler:      gc
Platform:      linux/amd64
Linkmode:      dynamic
```

### runc

```
$ runc --version
runc version spec: 1.0.1-dev
```

### Kubernetes

1.18

### Podman version

1.6.4

### iptables/nft

I am using nft with the iptables compatability layer.

```
$ iptables --version
iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables)
```

### Provider of host:

Contabo VPS

### sysctl

```
$ sysctl net.bridge
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-filter-pppoe-tagged = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-pass-vlan-input-dev = 0
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

### selinux disabled

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux

# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these three values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

### ip addr list

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether REDACTED brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet REDACTED scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: cni0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c6:00:41:85:da:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.85.0.1/16 brd 10.85.255.255 scope global noprefixroute cni0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1440 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
    inet 192.168.249.128/32 brd 192.168.249.128 scope global tunl0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: You are switching between different cni plugins? You used kubeadm to install k8s?share kubelet logs

Comment: Can You check if all k8s system pods are running? You can verify that with `kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system`.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Do you mean systemd logs? E.g. `journalctl -xe --unit kubelet`.

Comment: yes systemd logs using journalctl

Comment: @PiotrMalec I included the output of your command. All pods except coredns are running.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I included the logs but it's the same message over and over again. You can find more logs below the "journald logs" heading

Comment: Yes this looks like an issue caused by missing/miss-configured CNI plugin. Like @ArghyaSadhu suggested.

Comment: What does that mean exactly? I am pretty new to Kubernetes. Do you mean CNI plugins like Calico or Flannel? Prior to posting my answer I installed Calico sucessfully but then I also got the same "permission denied" and "ContainerCreating" errors for the nodes. However, I reverted the changes and started from scratch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Holy Hand Grenade of Antioch! I finally fixed it! It only took me, what, about a bazillion years and a restless-night. Sweet Victory! Well... ehm. On to the solution.

I finally understand the comments by @Arghya Sadhu and @Piotr Malec and they were right. I didn't configure my CNI-plugin correctly. I am using Flannel as a network provider and they require a 10.244.0.0/16 subnet. In my crio-bridge.conf found in /etc/cni/net.d/ the default subnet was different (10.85.0.0/16 or something). I thought it would be enough to specify the CIDR on the kubeadm init command but I was wrong. You need to set the correct CIDR in the crio-bridge.conf and podman.conflist (or similar files in the directory). I also thought those files that were installed with CRI-O were configured with reasonable defaults and, to be honest, I didn't fully understand what they were for.

Also something strange happened: According to Flannel the subnet for CRI-O should be /16 but when I checked the logs with journalctl -u kubelet it mentioned a /24 subnet.

```
failed to set bridge addr: \"cni0\" already has an IP address different from 10.244.0.1/24"
```

So I had to change the subnet in crio.conf to /24 and it worked. I probably have to change the subnet in the podman.conflist too, but I am not sure.

Anyway, thanks to Arghya and Piotr for their help!

Answer (score 1):

To setup a cluster with Calico network plugin and cri-o container runtime, I had to:

Add to `/etc/crio/crio.conf`

```
[crio.network]
network_dir = "/etc/cni/net.d/"
plugin_dirs = [
    "/opt/cni/bin/",
    "/usr/libexec/cni/",
]
```

Add `--cgroup-driver=systemd` in `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env`

```
KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS="--cgroup-driver=systemd --container-runtime=remote --container-runtime-endpoint=/var/run/crio/crio.sock --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.5"
```

Restart `kubelet` and `crio`

```
systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart kubelet crio
```

Initialize cluster

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr='10.85.0.0/16'
```

Install calico network plugin

```
kubectl create -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml
```